# R: date formatting ignores timezone for POSIXlt objects

Tags: r, timezone, posixct, posixlt

I cannot get R to format `POSIXlt` objects in the desired timezone. `POSIXct` works as expected. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

```
date.str = "2015-12-09 13:30"
from = "Europe/London"
to = "America/Los_Angeles"

lt = as.POSIXlt(date.str, tz=from)
format(lt, tz=to, usetz=TRUE)
#[1] "2015-12-09 13:30:00 GMT"

ct = as.POSIXct(date.str, tz=from)
format(ct, tz=to, usetz=TRUE)
#[1] "2015-12-09 05:30:00 PST"
```

The `tzone` attributes are the same:

```
attributes(ct)$tzone
#[1] "Europe/London"
attributes(lt)$tzone
#[1] "Europe/London"
```

**Solution**

As pointed out by @nicola, `format.POSIXlt` has no `tz` parameter. To print a `POSIXlt` date in another timezone one can use `lubridate` package to convert a `POSIXlt` object to the desired timezone first:

```
require(lubridate)
lt.changed = with_tz(lt, tz=to)
format(lt.changed, usetz=TRUE)
#[1] "2015-12-09 05:30:00 PST"
```

Comment: Slightly confused with what you are trying to achieve. Your output is correct `13:30 GTM` is `05:30 PST` and `ct == lt` in your example hence why the `tzone` attributes are the same. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: See `formalArgs(format.POSIXct)` and `formalArgs(format.POSIXlt)`: the `tz` argument doesn't exist for `POSIXlt` objects.

Comment: @amwill04, I want to print time in a certain zone as UTC time.

Comment: @nicola, nice trick, thanks!

Comment: There's no need for lubridate here at all - just `format(as.POSIXct(lt), tz=to, usetz=TRUE)` and you're done.